# RestSharp Returning Unauthorized in When making an API CAll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

I am trying to make an api call to one of our internal services,

I am using RESTSharp.

Normally If I am using postman to call the service, I first generate a jwt token, then pass the token into the secured endpoint as a query param.

To replicate this in RestSharp, I did this:

```
 public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationToken(CancellationToken token)
 {
   var options = new RestClientOptions(_baseUrl);
   using var client = new RestClient(options)
   {

   };

   var request = new RestRequest(_resource)
     .AddParameter("client_id", _clientId)
     .AddParameter("client_secret", _clientSecret)
     .AddParameter("grant_type", _grantType)
     .AddParameter("password", _password)
     .AddParameter("username", _username);
   var response = await client.PostAsync<TokenResponseDto>(request);
   return response.Access_Token;
            
 }
```

then this is how I called the secured endpoint:
the accesstoken is just jwt token.

```
        public async Task<CustomerResponseDto> GetCustomerDetailsByAccountNumber(CustomerRequestDto accountDetails, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var acccestoken = await GetAuthorizationToken(token);
            Console.WriteLine(acccestoken);
            accountDetails.AccountType = _acct_type;
            var options = new RestClientOptions(_baseUrl);
            using var client = new RestClient(options)
            {
                
            };
            var request = new RestRequest(_customer_resource)
                .AddParameter("access_token", acccestoken)
                .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .AddJsonBody(accountDetails);
            var response = await client.PostAsync<CustomerResponseDto>(request);

            return response;
        }
```

this is a sample url of how I called it in postman and It worked, it returned the records as expected

[http://x.x.x.x:{port}/{service}/secured/{customer_resource}?access_token={auth_token}](http://x.x.x.x:%7Bport%7D/%7Bservice%7D/secured/%7Bcustomer_resource%7D?access_token=%7Bauth_token%7D)

I have tried all the things I could yet no solution.

Additional Information:

1. This is the constructor for the Class
2. **Note the jwt token generates**

```
        public CustomerRespository(string clientId, string acctstmresource, string customer_resource, string clientSecret, string grantType, string password, string username, string baseUrl, string resource, string baseUrl2, string correlationId, string xclient, string resource2, string bankcode, string acct_type)
        {
            _clientId = clientId;
            _clientSecret = clientSecret;
            _grantType = grantType;
            _password = password;
            _username = username;
            _baseUrl = baseUrl;
            _resource = resource;
            _baseUrl2 = baseUrl2;
            _correlationId = correlationId;
            _xclient = xclient;
            _resource2 = resource2;
            _bankcode = bankcode;
            _acctstmresource = acctstmresource;
            _customer_resource = customer_resource;
            _acct_type = acct_type;

        }
```

Error Message:

```
Request Failed with status Unauthorized
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.<PostAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CCMP.Persistence.Repositories.CustomerRespository.<GetCustomerDetailsByAccountNumber>d__17.MoveNext() in E:\source\repos\CCMP-API\CCMP.Persistence\Repositories\CustomerRespository.cs:line 83
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CCMP.Application.Services.CustomerService.<GetCustomer>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\source\repos\CCMP-API\CCMP.Application\Services\CustomerService.cs:line 27
```

Kindly Help This is my fisrt time using RestSharp.

Comment: what is the response from  "var response = await client.PostAsync<TokenResponseDto>(request);"

Comment: No response, just throws an Exception

Comment: what's error, can you add to your question ?

Comment: Try running the [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).  
  Intercept requests and responses from your system:  
1. Using Postman  
2. Using RestSharp  
    
Compare the requests/responses and eliminate the differences.  
PS. Run Fiddler before launching your apps/services

Comment: So I used Fiddler as advised, What I observed is I can't pass query parameters when setting the content type as Json in a put request.

I don't know if what I said made sense, That is what I thought I understand from what I observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `AddParameter`, you add a so-called Get or Post parameter. When you use `POST`, it will be added to the request *body*, and you want it to be a part of the *query*.

You need to use the following:

```
var request = new RestRequest(_customer_resource)
    .AddQueryParameter("access_token", acccestoken)
    .AddJsonBody(accountDetails);
```

You don't need to manually add `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers, RestSharp does it for you.